# Appcelerator alloy views slide

Tags: animation, view, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am using the Alloy MVC framework over Titanium and want to make a slideshow between views. When I swipe on the screen, I want to display the next/previous view with a slide effect from right to left or left to right.
I am using this code:

A tab in my index.xml:

```
<Tab title="Bilan" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
    <Window title="Bilan" id="bilanTab" onSwipe="doBilanSwipe">
    </Window>
</Tab>
```

The question view dynamically added and filled inside bilanTab:

```
<Alloy>
<Collection src="ReponsePossible">
<View id="questionContainer" class="container">
    <Label id="questionText" />
    <Button id="buttonNextQuestion">Question suivante</Button>
</View>
</Alloy>
```

and my two functions (3 with prevQuestion not printed here) inside index.js controller:

```
var previousQuestion;
var nextQuestion;

function doBilanSwipe(e){
    if (e.direction == 'left'){
        nextQuestion();
    }
    else if (e.direction == 'right'){
        prevQuestion();
    }
}



function nextQuestion(){
    if (questionsCurrentIndex < questions.length-1){
        questionsCurrentIndex++;
        $.previous = previousQuestion;
        $.next = Alloy.createController('question', questions.at(questionsCurrentIndex));
        nextQuestion = $.next;
        $.next.questionContainer.left = 320;
        $.bilanTab.add($.next.questionContainer);
        $.next.questionContainer.animate({left:0, duration:200});
        $.previous.questionContainer.animate({left:-320, duration:200},function(){
            $.previous = previousQuestion;
            $.next = nextQuestion;
            $.bilanTab.remove($.previous.questionContainer);
            previousQuestion = $.next;
            $.previous.destroy();
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that first animation (first view moving to the left) is ok but after that, the next view just appear without any animation.

Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already the [`Titanium.UI.ScrollableView`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView) that does this exact thing, for all platforms.

Use it in Alloy like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win">
        <ScrollableView id="scrollableView" showPagingControl="true">
            <View id="view1" backgroundColor="#123" />
            <View id="view2" backgroundColor="#246" />
            <View id="view3" backgroundColor="#48b" />
        </ScrollableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

You can dynamically add views to it inside the controller like this:

```
$.scrollableView.addView(Ti.UI.createView({ // your custom attributes here});
```